# Can a Scheduled Job using mail_report send Reports as HTML in the e-mail body, rather than as a PDF attached to the e-mail?

Tags: civimail, civireport, scheduled-job

We're on CiviCRM 4.6.19 and Drupal 7.50 .

I'm having problems with six daily Scheduled Jobs to send reports using Job and mail_report and instanceId=x. Three of the reports get sent successfully, and three do not. There's an error reported with DOMPDF when executing the three failures manually as well. It's not an error with the e-mails being blocked as spam.

So: **Is there an option to send a report as HTML in an e-mail as a Scheduled Job, rather than as an attached PDF file? Is there a parameter for mail_report to send as HTML?**

Or: **Is there another API option to do this besides mail_report?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send a report as printer-friendly HTML, in the body of a Scheduled Job e-mail, using mail_report.

Go to Administer -> System Settings -> Scheduled Jobs. Edit the Scheduled Job parameters to add format=print, which overrides the default option, which is to send the report as a PDF file attached to the e-mail.

See [here](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs) for more information about managing Scheduled Jobs, including parameter options.

Comment: That's great - thanks for circling back on this to SE